# ASP.NET Configurable Web Service

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a web service reference in a ASP.NET 2.0 web site project.  I'd like to be able to switch between staging and production versions of the service without having to change my code.

However, I'm not seeing how to do that in a clean way.  I know that I can change web.config to point to some other service URL, but then isn't my code still hard-coded to one reference or the other?

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141237/making-a-web-service-reference-configuarble-asp-net), but how do you edit the proxy class?  If I "Go to Definition" on the class, it doesn't take me to any class that I can edit, but it's the object browser...  Do I need to run the wsdl.exe utility so that it will generate a proxy class for me that I can then edit?

**Edit #1:** Here's the code I'm using to instantiate and call the service:

```
Dim service As New Swan.MagellanLeadSheetService()
Dim response As Swan.MagellanLeadSheetResponse = service.Foo(stuffToSendToService)
```

**Edit #2:** Since the web.config already has the URL endpoint address in the appSettings area, can I just simply edit that setting when we deploy to Production to point to the production URL?  Is it that simple?  I was worried about the potential for breaking changes between the proxy classes of Staging vs. Production, but those should be resolved prior to deploying any changes to Production I think.

Comment: You may be having two difficulties: one, you're stuck using .NET 2.0, so you're stuck using ASMX web services, which are a legacy technology that should not be used for new development, and two: you're using a web site instead of a web application project. Web sites shouldn't be used for anything except the simplest applications. The fact that you're using a web service means you don't have the simplest application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following article explains how you can make the Web Service Reference dynamic by changing the reference properties, adding a key to the web.config file and referencing this key on the application code:

[Article Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12317/How-to-make-your-Web-Reference-proxy-URL-dynamic)

Basically you will have 2 versions of web.config file, production and staging with different URLs defined. While the code will point to a unique location.

**UPDATE:**

Now, before the following line, you have to alter the service.URL according to what stands in the web.config.

```
Dim response As Swan.MagellanLeadSheetResponse = service.Foo(stuffToSendToService)
```

Comment: I read the article, but my solution looks different.  In my web.config, it already added a reference to the web.config in appSettings to the staging version of the service.  However, I don't see any Reference.cs (or any .vb since I'm in a VB project).  I have an "App_WebReferences" folder with the namespace folder under it, with a .discomap file under that, and with the .wsdl under that.  Looking outside Studio, there's no other files than the .discomap and .wsdl.  I'm in Visual Studio 2010 in a VB.NET 2.0 project.

Comment: Can you post the code you use to create a new web service instance and call the service? You may also add the VB.net tag in the question.

Comment: Here's the code to init the service instance: Dim service As New Swan.MagellanLeadSheetService().  (So the name I gave the service when adding the reference was "Swan".)  If I right-click "Go to Definition" on that class, I go to the Object Browser instead of some Reference.vb or whatever.  To send the data, I'm just doing service.Foo(stuffToSend).  What do you mean by VB.net tag?

Comment: I meant editing your question, putting the code there and adding a new tag VB.net so people know it is related to it before entering to read the question. Code on comments are totally uncool to read.

Comment: Ok I added 2 edits in the main question including the code from my comment.

Answer (score 1):

First of all here is some info how to add a web reference to your project:

[How to: Add and Remove Web References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9w023sx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Then instance of your webservice class (the proxy class that derives from `SoapHttpClientProtocol`) has to have an property called url, with that property you can swith at runtime to your asmx from staging or production.

```
CountryService service = new CountryService();
service.Url = "http://foo/bar.asmx";
```

More info: [WebClientProtocol.Url Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.webclientprotocol.url.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I added the web reference correctly as in the link you provided.  However, after doing so, there is no visible proxy class within my solution.  No class is deriving from SoapHttpClientProtocol.  Could this be a VB.NET vs. C# difference?

Comment: Not that I know, did visual studio created a Reference.cs?

Comment: I'm in a VB.NET website.  No Reference.cs or Reference.vb file was created (also doesn't appear in the file explorer when looking outside Visual Studio).